# Creating <li> items depending on retrieved JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

My problem is as follows:

I have a NoSQL database with variable documents. For example one document will contain 5 fields and others contain 7 fields.
Now I have this panel which will show the following data:

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="Opdracht" class="collapse">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading text-center">{{title}}</div>
                <div class="panel-body" onload="show({{ex}})">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"> Beschrijving: {{description}}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">score: {{score}}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Extra opdracht: {{extra}}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">extra te verdienen punten: {{extra_score}}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">totaal te verdienen: {{score + extra_score}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <a href="#Opdracht" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Close</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem with this code is that they have a hardcoded and static amount(fixed number) of `<li>`. I want to write a function with, perhaps, a foreach function that creates a `<li>` that contains the kay value like :

```
 <li class="list-group-item">score: {{score}}</li>
```

I want to know that how this function would like and how can I bind it to the event where the panel loads.

If it helps:
I am using Bootstrap and AngularJS at client-side, Mongoose and nodeJS at Server-side.

Comment: Do you know [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your document code will be like:

```
$scope.users = [
{
        'title' : 'dsfsdf',
        'ex' : 'dsfsdf',
        'lists' : {
         'description' : 'dsfsdf',
        'score' : 'sdfsdf',
        'extra' : 'dsfsdf',
        'extra_scope' : 'dsfs' 
        }
    },
    {
        'title' : 'dfssf',
        'ex' : 'sfdsdf',
        'lists' : {
         'description' : 'dsfsdf',
        'score' : 'sdfsdf',
        'extra' : 'dsfsdf',
        'extra_scope' : 'dsfs',
        'second_extra' : 'sdfsdf'
        }
    },
    {
        'title' : 'dsfdsf',
        'ex' : 'sdfsf',
        'lists' : {
         'description' : 'dsfsdf',
        'score' : 'sdfsdf',
        'extra' : 'dsfsdf',
        'extra_scope' : 'dsfs',
        'second_extra' : 'sdfsdf',
        'third_extra' : 'sdfsdf',
        }
    }
];
```

Your HTML will be like

```
 <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="user in users">
                <div class="panel-heading text-center">{{user.title}}</div>
                <div class="panel-body" onload="show({{user.ex}})">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="(key, val) in user.lists">{{key}} : {{val}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <a href="#Opdracht" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Close</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Refer This [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/blIn4AwVr4YX174W0SZR?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

**Use ng-repeat**

```
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="score in data">
     {{ score }}
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: but this will not create <li> for each property in the JSON string, will it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-repeat` to get both the key and the property.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

When used with this example data:

```
$scope.data = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
```

It would produce the following HTML.

```
<ul>
  <li>a: 1</li>
  <li>b: 2</li>
  <li>c: 3</li>
</ul>
```